# discovering which admin performed an action in Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-signals

I am trying to set up a system where every time something happens in the admin console (let's say, a user is saved), a certain set of people gets notified.  I hooked up post_save and 
it works fine.  I can retrieve most of the data I need (which user and what fields were saved) from the instance passed into the callback function.  However, there's one thing in the requirements, which I can't figure out how to do and that is to show, which particular admin made the change.  Any ideas on how that can be done?

Thank you,
Luka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go through the database, you will discover that you have the table `django_admin_log` which lists what changes were made by what admin and even has a `change_message` . Maybe you can create a view for this table and play around with the queries.